# Multiply ticklabel values in colorbar when plotting matrix with imshow

Tags: python, colorbar, imshow

I have a matrix and I plot it with imshow.

The colorbar is created like this:

```
cbar=pl.colorbar(shrink=0.3, aspect=10)
tick_locator = ticker.MaxNLocator(nbins=5)
cbar.locator = tick_locator
cbar.ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.ticker.AutoLocator())
cbar.update_ticks()
```

As you can see in [my example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/apffmg1b5hr17cf/example.png) there are lots of zeros in my scale... I want to multiply the number in the scale with a factor (so that I can cange e.g. the units from K(elvin) to mK)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to multiply your data with a certain factor,

```
pl.imshow(factor*numpy.array(matrix))
```

Or

```
pl.imshow(factor*matrix)
```

If your matrix already is a numpy array.